# Manipulate value of child node attribute in a cloned div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am cloning the following div in my jsp:

```
    <div id="row" class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label">
                <label for="name"><b> Select Name: </b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="control-label">
                <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled" label="Select a name"></option>                                                                                                    
                        <option value="1">Bradley</option>   
                        <option value="2">Anderson</option>
                        <option value="3">Sonya</option>    
                </select>
            </div>          
            <div class="control-label">
                <label for="ranks"><b> Rank :  </b></label>
                <input type="text" value="1" name="rank" id="rank" readonly="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am executing the cloning in javascript:

```
var i = 0;
function duplicate() {
  var original = document.getElementById('row');
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "row" + ++i;
  if(!document.getElementById('row3')){
      original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, document.getElementById('nextDiv')); //nextDiv not shown in jsp for simplification
  } 
}
```

How do I access the value of "rank" so that every time the div is cloned, the value increments by 1?

Basically I want something like clone.getElementById('rank') though I know that's not right syntax. I tried clone.setAttribute('rank', i++) but the setAttribute only accesses the attributes of the div and not the child node in the div. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Should all elements within cloned node which have `id` have `id` incremented ? e.g., `#names` , `#rank` ?

Comment: Note that id's have to be unique. take a look at [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) to see what methods your `clone` node has.

Comment: No, name id does not have to be incremented. Just the rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Array.prototype.forEach()` , `for` loop, `Element.children` to increment `id`, `for`, `value` properties of cloned element `.control-label` elements child nodes . Note, `for` attributes at `label` elements  should correspond to `id` of `select` , `input` elements; added `"s"` at `for="names"` , `for="ranks"` `label` elements

```js
var i = 0;

function duplicate() {
  var original = document.getElementById('row');
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "row" + ++i;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(clone.querySelectorAll(".control-label")
  , function(el, index) {
    for (var j = 0; j < el.children.length; j++) {
      // increment `id` 
      if (el.children[j].id !== "") {
        el.children[j].id = el.children[j].id + i;
      }
      // increment `for` attribute
      if (el.children[j].htmlFor !== "") {
        el.children[j].htmlFor = el.children[j].htmlFor + i;
      } 
      // increment `#ranks`-n `value`         
      if (el.children[j].name === "ranks") {
        el.children[j].value = 1 + Number(el.children[j].value)
      }
    }
  })

  if (!document.getElementById('row3')) {
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, 
    // nextDiv not shown in jsp for simplification
    document.getElementById('nextDiv')); 
  }
}

duplicate()
```

```html
<div id="row" class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">
      <label for="names"><b> Select Name: </b>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-label">
      <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" label="Select a name"></option>
        <option value="1">Bradley</option>
        <option value="2">Anderson</option>
        <option value="3">Sonya</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-label">
      <label for="ranks"><b> Rank :  </b>
      </label>
      <input type="text" value="1" name="ranks" id="ranks" readonly="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="nextDiv"></div>
```

Comment: For the queryselectorAll, if my bootstrap formatting changes from control-label to col-lg-3 control-label, should the syntax then be clone.querySelectorAll('.col-lg-3 control-label')?

Comment: @RJK If `className` of `control-label` is changed to `col-lg-3` , could adjust to `.querySelectorAll(".col-lg-3")`

Comment: I think solution will work, but for some reason I am having trouble setting the right class element in querySelectorAll.

Comment: _"but for some reason I am having trouble setting the right class element in querySelectorAll."_ Using same `html` at Question ?

Comment: Right now, my child elements class is like so:


'col-lg-3 control-label' FOR NAMES


'col-lg-4' FOR SELECT


'col-lg-3 control-label' FOR RANK

I understand this is different than original post, I apologize, but how would I capture this?

Comment: Use same process as described at Answer. Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: Jsfiddle would help.

querySelectorAll('.col-lg-3 control-label') doesn't seem to work. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: This solution works when class is same for all child elements. Can't seem to figure it how it would work when it is different though. Nevertheless, solution answers question asked. +1

Comment: Missing `.` at selector, try `querySelectorAll('.col-lg-3 .control-label')`

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the . selector in the comment, but didn't forget in my code. Does all child elements need same class for this to work?

Comment: @RJK _"Does all child elements need same class for this to work?"_ Not certain interpret correctly ?